# Java Calendar calculate next Friday of odd week

Tags: java, date, calendar

I'd like to get the next Friday of even week (considerning the weeks of the year numbered from 1 to 54).

For example if today is Friday and the week is even I want the next Friday. If today is Thursday of an odd week I want the date of tomorrow.

The test input / output is the following:

```
 14/09/2012 -> 14/09/2012
 15/09/2012 -> 28/09/2012
 21/09/2012 -> 28/09/2012
 22/09/2012 -> 28/09/2012
 29/09/2012 -> 12/10/2012
 25/12/2012 -> 04/01/2013
 29/12/2012 -> 04/01/2013
```

Comment: what if today is Friday and the week is odd?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfWeek = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
int daysUntilNextFriday = Calendar.FRIDAY - dayOfWeek;
if(daysUntilNextFriday < 0){
    daysUntilNextFriday = daysUntilNextFriday + 7;
}
Calendar nextFriday = (Calendar)today.clone();
nextFriday.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, daysUntilNextFriday);
if(nextFriday.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) % 2 == 0){
    nextFriday.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 7);
}
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(nextFriday.getTime()));
```

Comment: it does not work for "09/14/2012", it returns de 28th. The 14th is fine.

Comment: I modified the assignment of nextFriday to do `today.clone()` instead of `Calendar.getInstance()`. Try now.

Comment: for "09/15/2012" returns "09/14/2012"

Comment: Ah I see, I misunderstood your question. I believe it now works as expected.